# How to get the bounds of exponential function

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

I have this function $(\frac{d}{d+1})^d$. How can I get the lower and upper bound of this function

Comment: What do you know about the function that might help?  You should edit the question to include your thoughts on the problem.

Comment: Also, you labeled this as "complex analysis".  Should we assume that $d$ is a complex variable?

Comment: More detail on the problem statement would help too. What is the domain of $d$? Is *any* upper and lower bound good enough or do you want the least and greatest ones?

Comment: @user75300 : you labelled your question "complex analysis".  For arbitrary complex numbers $z$ and $w$, there is no standard definition of $z^w$, and if $d$ is not real, $({\frac{d}{d+1}})^d$ may not be real even if it is well-defined, so "lower bound" and "upper bound" make no sense.  The question has nothing to do with algorithms either.

Comment: user: your account has not been suspended. Please do not deface content, unless you really *do* want your account to be suspended.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{2}\geq\left(\frac{d}{d+1}\right)^d=\left(\frac{1}{1+1/d}\right)^d\geq\frac{1}{e}$$

Comment: I disagree that $\left(\frac{d}{d+1}\right)^d\leq \frac{1}{2}$, consider $d=0$.

Comment: Surely we can say $\left(\frac{d}{d+1}\right)^d\leq 1$, though!